# numpy arange: how to make "precise" array of floats?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In short, the problem I encounter is this:

```
aa = np.arange(-1., 0.001, 0.01)
aa[-1]
Out[16]: 8.8817841970012523e-16
```

In reality, this cause a series problem since my simulations doesn't allow positive value inputs.

I can sort of get around by doing:

```
aa = np.arange(-100, 1, 1)/100.
aa[-1]
Out[21]: 0.0
```

But this is a pain. Practically you can't do this every time.

This seems like such a basic problem. There's gotta be something I am missing here.
By the way, I am using Python 2.7.13.

Comment: `linspace` helps but doesn't solve everything.

Comment: Yep, I use linspace sometimes. But you know sometimes arange is more convenient:)

Comment: Try using `linspace`. Floats have some noise by nature, and arange does not work (precisely) with non-integer increments. Or if you must, manually set the last element to 0.0.

Comment: Have they fixed this in python 3?

Comment: The fundamental limits of representing real numbers with finite bits cannot be fixed by a version upgrade.

Comment: If you don't want positive values, why don't you stop at 0 ? `aa = np.arange(-1., 0, 0.01)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This happens because Python (like most modern programming languages) uses floating point arithmetic, which cannot exactly represent some numbers (see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)).

This means that, regardless of whether you're using Python 2, Python 3, R, C, Java, etc. you have to think about the effects of adding two floating point numbers together.

`np.arange` works by repeatedly adding the `step` value to the `start` value, and this leads to imprecision in the end:

```
>>> start = -1
>>> for i in range(1000):
...    start += 0.001
>>> start
8.81239525796218e-16
```

Similarly:

```
>>> x = np.arange(-1., 0.001, 0.01)
>>> x[-1]
8.8817841970012523e-16
```

The typical pattern used to circumvent this is to work with integers whenever possible if repeated operations are needed. So, for example, I would do something like this:

```
>>> x = 0.01 * np.arange(-100, 0.1)
>>> x[-1]
0.0
```

Alternatively, you could create a one-line convenience function that will do this for you:

```
>>> def safe_arange(start, stop, step):
...    return step * np.arange(start / step, stop / step)

>>> x = safe_arange(-1, 0.001, 0.01)
>>> x[-1]
0
```

But note that even this can't get around the limits of floating point precision; for example, the number -0.99 **cannot be represented** exactly in floating point:

```
>>> val = -0.99
>>> print('{0:.20f}'.format(val))
-0.98999999999999999112
```

So you must always keep that in mind when working with floating point numbers, in any language.

Answer (score 3):

Using np.linespace solved it for me:

For example `np.linspace(0.5, 0.9, 5)` produce [0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9].

Answer (score 0):

We don't get to forget about the limitations of floating-point arithmetics. Repeatedly adding 0.01, or rather the double-precision float that is close to 0.01, will result in the kind of effects you observe.

To ensure that an array does not contain positive numbers, use [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```
aa = np.clip(np.arange(-1., 0.001, 0.01), None, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. `np.clip` works for this specific problem. But all the other elements in the array are still slightly off. Unfortunately, it seems that's the way it is then.

Comment: Yes, that is the way it is. 0.1+0.2 == 0.3 is `False` and we have to live with that (in Python 3, too, as well as in other languages).  See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem as you do.

Here is a simple solution:

```
for b in np.arange(maxb,minb+stepb,stepb):    
    for a in np.arange(mina,maxa+stepa,stepa):        
        a=round(a,2);b=round(b,2); # 2 is the size of the floating part.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).