# How do I EXTRACT all values ending in .000 and print them?

Tags: python

OK so I have a for loop running an equation iterating it a 0.005. I need it to print any "L" value ending in .000 and nothing else. How do I do that?

```
import numpy as np
import math
for D in np.arange(7, 9, 0.0050):
    N = 28
    n = 11
    A = 7.32
    P = 0.25
    C =  float(D)/float(P) #(P/8)*(2*L-N-n+((2*L-N-n)**(2)-0.810*(N-n)**(2))**(0.5)
    L = 2*C+(N+n)/2+A/C
    print("L = ", "%.3f"% float(L), '\n')
```

Problems I had:

I had to use np.arange as it wouldn't allow a float in a loop. If you can show me how to get around that, that'd be great.

When using np.arange, I would get "D" values like

```
D = 7.0009999999999994
L = 75.76939122982431 

D = 7.001499999999999
L = 75.7733725630222 

D = 7.001999999999999
L = 75.77735389888602 

D = 7.002499999999999
L = 75.78133523741519
```

this causes errors when I go to use these numbers later in the code

this loop takes forever to compute. If there's a better way, show me. I have to make this quick or it won't get used.

Comment: `if int(L) == L: ...`?

Comment: ^ This. Int() will truncate all decimal points, essentially flooring the number. If the decimals were .000 then the int should be equal to the float thus you can print.

Comment: You can get rid of np.arange by just using range as `for D in range(7000, 9000, 5):` and then using `D/1000`

Comment: Forever to compute? It finishes within a fraction of a second on my years old cell phone...

Comment: Something like ```if str('%.3f' % L).endswith('.000'):```?

Comment: @Bazingaa this is not true, the above described effect has nothing to do with using numpy or not, it's just about representability of floats using binary number systems - which all our machines do

Comment: See e.g. https://www.floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @SpghttCd: My comment was just to provide an alternative to using any external modules

Comment: @Bazingaa ah, sorry. In my eyes it read as a solution for their aforementioned problem about precision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`L3` is the variable

`"%.3f"%` is the 3rd decimal place

`% 1 == 0` I'm not sure what this does, but 0 is the number I'm looking for.

```
if float("%.3f"% L3) % 1 == 0: #L3 is the variable 
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 2):

This post explained why float is not working well in python:
[numpy arange: how to make "precise" array of floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243190/numpy-arange-how-to-make-precise-array-of-floats)

I used below code and it gave me precise decimal 3 numbers for both D & L in your calculation:

```
for i in range(7000, 9000, 5):
    D = i/1000

    print(D)

    N = 28
    n = 11
    A = 7.32
    P = 0.25
    C =  float(D)/float(P) #(P/8)*(2*L-N-n+((2*L-N-n)**(2)-0.810*(N-n)**(2))**(0.5)
    L = 2*C+(N+n)/2+A/C
    print("L = ", "%.3f"% float(L), '\n')
```